Image-to-Image with U-Net with no Skip-connections. Is it real?
In general, U-Net is needed to create another style image, but preserve the structure. For example, a full-fledged drawing from a sketch. Right?
I want to preserve the style, but change the structure. For example, I want to take a photo with crumpled fabric and get unfolded fabric. But i don't wanna use GAN. For this I decided to remove Skip connectors from U-Net that preserve the structure. And also I convolve the input image to the style vector like in GAN. Right?
The problem is that this code trains successfully but only if there is no augmentation in the training database. As soon as I add to the input image (only to the input, since the output should remain unchanged) an angular augmentation of +/- 5, 10 and 15 degrees, then instead of the result I get some noise. If I start training on a dataset of several examples, then the result is correct when applying augmentation. But as the number of examples in the dataset increases, the result gets worse.
But anyway my curve (Loss:MSE) is perfect ))) I mean, even if I get some noise as a result (image), my curve looks like I get a perfect result. Just falling curve. And this is what annoys me the most. I don't understand how it is possible. Even if i get some noise as a result (image) curve is falling down like everything is fine. Approximately 0,09/0.05/0.02/0.01/.... I call it overfiitting just because i don't know what it is. I mean when i don't get correct result but you get falling loss curve it is called overfitting. Right ?
And about capacity of my model. Of course, I thought about it and changed the number of layers, filters in layers and neurons in dense layers but to no avail. So I think there is some conceptual problem here.
I use some examples from training dataset as a validation because i wanna be sure this model can do right at least my training data. But, as i say before, with augmentation i get some noise with perfect loss(MSE). No matter how many epoch i use - result is trash, curve is perfect. Learning rate = 0.00006 * K (K = 5,4,3,2,1). Input/output - image (2562563). Adam.
l2_reg = regularizers.l2(1e-6)
initializer = initializers.he_normal()


def build_unet(input_shape=(256, 256, 3)):
   inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)


   c = layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(inputs)
   c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c) 

   c = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
   c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)

   c = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
   c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)

   c = layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
   c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)

   c = layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
   c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)

   c = layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(c)
   c = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(c)


   # Bottle-neck
   b = InstanceNormalization()(c)

   b = layers.Reshape((-1,))(b)
   b = layers.Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg,)(b)
   b = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(b)

   b = layers.Dropout(0.2)(b)

   b = layers.Dense(1024*4*4, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg,)(b)
   b = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(b)
   b = layers.Reshape((4,4,1024))(b)


   # Декодер
   d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(b)
   d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

   d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
   d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

   d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
   d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

   d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
   d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

   d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
   d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)

   d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(d)
   d = layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2)(d)


   outputs = layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="tanh")(d)

   model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="build_unet")
   return model


unet = build_unet()

adam_optimizer = Adam(
   learning_rate=0.00006*K,
  )

unet.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, loss='mse', metrics= None)


What does your input and output look like? What is the output that you are getting after training the model?  What problem are you trying to solve?

In general, U-Net is needed to create another style image, but preserve the structure. For example, a full-fledged drawing from a sketch. Right?
But I want to preserve the style, but change the structure.
For example, from a photo of any cat, make a photo of the same cat, but always in a same pose on a white background. Or I want to take a photo with crumpled fabric and get unfolded fabric.
But i don't wanna use GAN.
For this I decided to remove Skip connectors from U-Net that preserve the structure. And also I convolve the input image to the style vector like in GAN. Right?

I understand your points, but that does not answer my question. Without getting more details about your problem, just knowing that you did not apply skip connections is not enough information to debug anything. Please provide more details.

The problem is that this code trains successfully but only if there is no augmentation in the training database. As soon as I add to the input image (only to the input, since the output should remain unchanged) an angular augmentation of +/- 5, 10 and 15 degrees, then instead of the result I get some garbage. If I start training on a dataset of several examples, then the result is correct when applying augmentation. But as the number of examples in the dataset increases, the result gets worse.

What do your training curves look like? It is possible that your model does not have enough capacity to learn these input variations.

My curve (Loss:MSE) is perfect ))) I mean, even if I get garbage as a result, my curve looks like I get a perfect result. Just falling curve. And this is what annoys me the most. It looks like overfitting, but it, as I thought, should occur after achieving some result, but here there is no result. Just overfitting. And about capacity. Of course, I thought about it and changed the number of layers, filters in layers and neurons in dense layers but to no avail. So I think there is some conceptual problem here.

How can your loss curve loop be perfect when you say that your result is garbage?  Please edit your question to include what is this garbage output. So when you say overfitting, do you mean that you do not get garbage results for the training data? Because that is not mentioned in the question. What does the loss curve of your validation set look like?

Add more information like training epochs, learning rate, types of input-output. The question as it stands right now is incomplete.

Also recommend posting the question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://ai.stackexchange.com/

I don't understand how it is possible as well. Even if i get some noise as a result (image) curve is falling down like everything is fine. Approximately 0,09/0.05/0.02/0.01/.... I call it overfiitting just because i don't know what it is. I mean when i don't get correct result but you get falling loss curve it is called overfitting. Right ?

I use some examples from training dataset as a validation because i wanna be sure this model can do right at least my training data. But, as i say before, with augmentation i get some noise with perfect loss(MSE).
No matter how many epoch i use - result is trash, curve is down. Learning rate = 0.00006 * K (K = 5,4,3,2,1). Input/output - image (2562563).  Adam.

I am going to request one more time to please edit your post and add the extra details you just mentioned in your comments. This is not for me, but for other folks who may be able to help you. "Approximately 0,09/0.05/0.02/0.01/.... I call it overfiitting just because i don't know what it is. " -> Please plot these curves for your train and val sets, and add them to the post. At least we will know what is happening during training.
